# Problemas com **UL inline**

Tags: html, css

Boas,

Eu tenho um problema em fazer um **ul** **inline** [assim](http://gyazo.com/4ffa72292718415d3c51bc9cd1d70891) pois sempre que tento por **hr** e **vertical-align** sai sempre do sitio.

Este é o resultado que me dá:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#000000;
}

a:hover{
 color:#3ba09e;
}
   hr{
width:20px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>

<li><a href="#"><h4>Arquivo<h4/> <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/bolinha.png"/><hr></hr></a></li>

<li><a href="#"><h4>Escritórios</h4> <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/bolinha.png"/><hr></hr></a></li>

<li><a href="#"><h4>Escolas</h4> <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/bolinha.png"/><hr></hr></a></li>

<li><a href="#"><h4>Outros</h4> <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/bolinha.png"/><hr></hr></a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você digitou errado os atributos do `hr`.

```
hr{
    with:20px;
    display:inline block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Está errado o `with` e `inline block`, correto é:

```
hr{
    width:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

E troque o `h4` por `span` e atribua o seletor da sua preferência.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#000000;
}

a:hover{
 color:#3ba09e;
}
   hr{
     width:20px;
     display:inline-block;
     vertical-align:middle;
     border: 1px solid red;
}

.textoMaior {
     font-size: 18px;
     font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>

<li><a href="#"><span class="textoMaior">Arquivo</span> <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/bolinha.png"/><hr></hr></a></li>

<li><a href="#"><span class="textoMaior">Escritórios</span> <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/bolinha.png"/><hr></hr></a></li>

<li><a href="#"><span class="textoMaior">Escolas</span> <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/bolinha.png"/><hr></hr></a></li>

<li><a href="#"><span class="textoMaior">Outros</span> <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/bolinha.png"/><hr></hr></a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Mesmo assim não sei como é que dá aquele espaçamento todo entre o **<h4>** e a imagem.

Comment: @BrunoGibellino Atualizei minha resposta com sua necessidade.

Comment: obrigado, mesmo isso que precisava. Mas com o background-color e com o color não dá para mudar a cor do hr. Será que estou a fazer bem?

Comment: @BrunoGibellino Utilizei `border-color` ao invés de `color`

Comment: Eu precisava mesmo de utilizar o **h4** e quando mudei o **span** para **h4** aquilo desformatou tudo. Não existe nenhuma maneira de utilizar **h4** com **ul**?

Comment: desformatou como?

Comment: Ao invés de ficar inline ficou tudo em linhas separadas

Comment: Verifica se não tem outro elemento ou seletor dando conflito